# Hide Useless tables in PhpStorm Database Tool Window

Tags: phpstorm

I am using **PhpStorm 2016.1.1** and Database Tools Window to manage **MySql** database tables.

Some Tables are Useless and rarely I visit them and are occupied Much space on the Database Tools Window.

Are there any way to hide Useless tables on the PhpStorm Database Tools Window?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Open the "Database" Tool Window and click on the "Data Source Properties" button on its small toolbar. The "Data Source and Drivers" dialog box opens.

Select your data source on the left side of the window (find it under the "Project Data Sources" section), open the "Schema" tab (on the right side of the window) and check the database(s) you want to see in the "Database" Window.

If you want to see only some tables from the checked databases then you put their names or regular expressions that match their names into the "Object filter" text box. A "-" (minus) in front of names or expressions is used to exclude the matching tables.

If there are many names to put in the list, press the "..." button on the right of the "Object filter" text box. The small window that shows up contains a multi-line text box that makes it easier to input the filtering rules (one per line).

Comment: I added my desired tables name like `role_user||org_level_user||contents||permissions||units||files||roles||users||courses||course_categories||course_org_level||permission_role||course_category_course||lessons||org_levels` in the object filter but none of them Not shown.

Comment: Are these the tables you want to hide? Put `-` in front of each of their names. Like this: `-role_user||-org_level_user||-contents||...`